# How to reference a foreign key on a non-MVC Razor page

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, foreign-keys, razor-pages

I have the following model with a foreign key (`public Agency Agency`):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DWITracker.Model
{
    public class Officer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Officer Name (Last, First, MI)")]
        public string? OfficerDisplayName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string? OfficerFirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "MI")]
        public string? OfficerMiddleInitial { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string? OfficerLastName { get; set; }
        public Agency Agency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When a user is updating this table (from a create view) with a new officer, I need them to be able to select the foreign key (using the `Agency` dropdown) so they can be assigned to an `Agency`.

For reference, here is the `Agency` model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DWITracker.Model
{
    public class Agency
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Agency")]
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have the foreign key so that I can use cascading dropdowns on another (unrelated to this) view page.

Here is my current `.cs` for this:

```
public IEnumerable<Agency> DisplayAgencyData { get; set; }

public async Task OnGet()
{
    await _db.Agency.Select(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
    DisplayAgencyData = await _db.Agency.ToListAsync();
}
```

And, here is the relevant portion of my view:

```
<td style="width: 40%">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Officer.Agency"></label>
        <select asp-for="Officer.Agency" id="Select3" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayAgencyData.OrderBy(x => x.AgencyName),"Id", "AgencyName"))">
            <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Associated Agency---</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

I have tried many different things, but I keep getting an error:

> The Agency field is required.

When I view the `Officer` table in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, I see that this field is called `AgencyId` rather than just `Agency`, but I cannot use that on my razor view without error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Please respond so a beginner can understand your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Officer` model, The type of `Agency` property is `Agency`. But in your dropdown list, the type of option's value is `int`, When you select an option and submit the form. A `int` value will attempt to bind to property of type `Agency`, Model binding will fail and the value of `Agency` property will be null, Because `Agency` is non-nullable, So you will get this error.

The solution is create a foreign key manually and bind the value of option to this foreign key.

```
[ForeignKey("Agency")]
public int AgencyId { get; set; }
public Agency? Agency { get; set; }
```

Then change your view code like:

```
<td style="width: 40%">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Officer.Agency"></label>
        <select asp-for="Officer.AgencyId " id="Select3" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayAgencyData.OrderBy(x => x.AgencyName),"Id", "AgencyName"))">
            <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Associated Agency---</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

**Note:** if your dotnet version is .Net 6 or .Net 7, You need to add `?` to `Agency` property to make it nullable. This is because we bind value to `AgencyId` instead of `Agency`, So the value of `Agency` will be null in Model binding, If `Agency` is non-nullable, the project will also show this error.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation. I had a feeling what was missing, but didn't know how to connect the dots! One other question, and please tell me if I should post a separate question is: How would I reference this Agency on the Index page? I would like to have the AgencyName display next to the Officers name on the index page as the FK won't mean much to anyone. I have added my Index view to the original post.